# Can you affect the Haunt roll with items, omens or other effects in Betrayal at House on the Hill?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

I was watching Wil Wheaton playing Betrayal at House on the Hill, and someone commented:

[image: A comment from youtube]

Can the Rabbits foot, or the Angels Feather (or anything else) avert the haunt? I can't see why not, but this seems like a special case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both the Rabbit's Foot and the Angel Feather have extremely generic text; the Rabbit's Foot says *once during your turn, you may reroll one die;* the Angel Feather says *When you attempt a roll of any kind...*

The only restriction I can see is that both the Rabbit's Foot and the Angel Feather must be used by the player who revealed the Omen card and is making the Haunt roll. Both of those items specifically restrict the affected roll to the owner's rolls. The rules state that a Haunt roll is made at the *end* of your turn, but that means it's still your turn.

TL;DR: **Yes, the owner of those items may affect a haunt roll that the owner makes.**

Comment: The official FAQ states you can use angel feather on another's turn. http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=ah/faqs/hoth

Comment: @Styphon you can use the feather, but only for your own rolls (such as when defending against an attack). The rules around Haunt rolls are vague on who makes the roll ("Make a haunt roll", and similar, is the phrasing used everywhere), but you can't use the Angel Feather on somebody else's haunt roll.